# Is there a PHP function(or combined functions) which can directly convert <time> in GPX to local time?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, simplexml, gpx

I am using `simplexml_load_file` to parse contains of a trip log file (`.GPX`). In it, the tag `<time>` records are of the GMT, and I am looking for a PHP funciton or a simple combination of PHP functions to convert it to my local time (GMT+8). I have looked through [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_date.asp) and still can not figure out what to do.

To be specific, is there any PHP function which takes in a string like "2013-11-22T04:14:30Z" and returns "2013-11-22 **12:14:30**" (I wish to display datetime in this format)? I know it can be achieved by writing a function by myself, but I think there could be a standard PHP function that does this.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, I followed the link you provided and found it works. It is just not as simple as what I have imagined PHP might have provided. Something like `timeconvfunc('2013-11-22T04:14:30Z',origTimeZone,convTimezone)`.

Comment: I don't think such a function exists, seeing as it would do two jobs at once - one, parse the time string, two, convert time zones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy using [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) & [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
$time = '2013-11-22T04:14:30';
$time_z = '2013-11-22T04:14:30Z';

$add_time = ' + 8 hours';

$unixtime = strtotime($time);
$unixtime_z = strtotime($time_z);

echo 'Unixtime: ' . date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $unixtime) . '<br />';
echo 'Unixtime Z: ' . date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $unixtime_z) . '<br />';

echo 'Unixtime (+ 8 hours): ' . date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $unixtime . $add_time) . '<br />';
echo 'Unixtime Z (+ 8 hours): ' . date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $unixtime_z . $add_time) . '<br />';
```

The output would be:

> **Unixtime:** 2013-11-22 04:14:30
>
> **Unixtime Z:** 2013-11-21 11:14:30
>
> **Unixtime (+ 8 hours):** 2013-11-22 04:14:30
>
> **Unixtime Z (+ 8 hours):** 2013-11-21 11:14:30

The key for this to work is the `$add_time` which is just me adding  `+ 8 hours` to the date string. But there are other methods to handle this based on your larger needs & input data.

Comment: Meh. A proper timezone conversion as shown in the duplicate link above would be much better - it's more flexible and, more importantly, takes into account DST which this code doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Jake! But the output of your code is '2013-11-22 08:14:30' instead of  '2013-11-22 12:14:30'. It will output the desired result only if I remove 'T' and 'Z' from the input string, like inputting this: '2013-11-22 04:14:30' instead of '2013-11-22T04:14:30Z'. I do not yet understand how it works.